# Conditional Formatting: Global Formatting Definitions?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

Lets say I have Sheet1 where

```
    A    B
1   foo  foo
2   bar  bar
```

and ReferenceSheet where

```
    A
1   bar  <-- cell is formatted with red background
2   foo  <-- cell is formatted with blue background
```

and where, as in all other programming examples, "bar" and "foo" are arbitrary placeholder values. :)

I would like to make it so that for each cell (A1:D4) in Sheet1 that matches the value of a definition cell in ReferenceSheet (A1:A2), the cell will automatically copy the formatting of the definition cell.

So that, continuing with the above example, Sheet1's background colors will be formatted as

```
    A    B
1   bl   bl
2   red  red
```

But if I change the ReferenceSheet's formatting to

```
    A
1   bar  <-- cell is formatted with pink background
2   foo  <-- cell is formatted with black background
```

Sheet1's background formatting will update to

```
    A    B
1   blk  blk
2   pk   pk
```

If possible, how does one go about implementing this?

======

*I would like to define my formatting in a sheet (rather than in Visual Basic code) in order to create more user-accessible formatting definitions. If that's not an option, Visual Basic (and therefore global) definitions would be my next choice.  Mass-copied conditional formatting applied to each cell would be my last choice, though finding a style-abstraction option similar to styles in Microsoft Word would make it a more paletable alternative.

Comment: Have you considered a `Worksheet_Change` Sub?

Answer (score 0):

A `Worksheet_Change Sub` will do what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Place Sub in only the Reference Worksheet

   'Do nothing if more than one cell is changed or content deleted
   If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

   With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("DefineRange").FormatConditions.Modify(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=" & Target.Value)
     .Interior.Color = Target.Interior.Color
   End With

End Sub
```

Edit:  I used `.Modify` because I assume you will already have a conditional format specified if a cell equals a certain value.  If you want to add a new conditional formatting rule, use `.Add` instead.